# Prove that $\vert\sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(2^2x)\cdots\sin(2^nx)\vert < \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, induction, contest-math, products

For $x$ in $\mathbb R^*$ and $n$ in $\mathbb N$, define

$$U_n = \sin(x)\sin(2x)\sin(2^2x)\cdots\sin(2^nx) = \prod_{k=0}^n\sin(2^k x)$$

Prove that $$\vert U_n\vert \leq \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^n$$

Can anyone help please.

---

(Edited by @River Li) I found it was B6(c) in the 34th Putnam (1973):

**B-6**: On the domain $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$:

(a) Prove that $\sin^2\theta \sin 2\theta$
takes its maximum at $\pi/3$ and $4\pi/3$
(and hence its maximum at $2\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3$).

(b) Show that
$$\left|\sin^2\theta \, \Big[\sin^3(2\theta)
\cdot \sin^3(4\theta) \cdots \sin^3(2^{n - 1}\theta)\Big]\, \sin (2^n\theta)\right|$$
takes its maximum at $\theta = \pi/3$.
(The maximum may also be attained at other points.)

(c) Derive the inequality:
$$\sin^2\theta \cdot \sin^2(2\theta) \cdot \sin^2(4\theta) \cdots \sin^2(2^n\theta)\le (3/4)^n.$$

[image: Putnam 1973 B6]

See: The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 81, No. 10, Dec., 1974, (Page 1086-1095)
or https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/putn73.html

Comment: The revised version of the question should be at least sensible now. What is still lacking is any sort of personal input from the OP.

Comment: i think 0 is allowed

Comment: Yeah, but with $\leq$; not $<$.

Comment: yeah it is ≤ i just failed sorry

Comment: i failed everything tho xd

Comment: multiply by $\cos(x)$ both sides and see what you get.

Comment: so does anyone got the answer  ?

Comment: @Did can u help please ?

Comment: Did you try to follow @frank000's suggestion? *Please explain in details how things went when you did*.

Comment: well , when i multiplied by cos(x) both sides i got cos(x).Un=1/2 . sin(2x)^2.sin(2^2 x)....sin(2^n x )

Comment: @Did so what do u think ?

Comment: That this does not look very promising... and that you still did not provide context.

Comment: @Did what do u mean.

Comment: can anyone help please ?

Comment: I think induction may help. Do you know about mathematical induction?

Comment: Yeah , but I don't know what u are looking for exactly

Comment: . @mathreadler ?

Comment: If you combine it with the multiplication by $\cos$ observation someone made i think it can help.

Comment: multiplication only by cos(x) or the prod cos(2^k .x) ? because i tried both of them , it didn't show me any result

Comment: . @mathreadler ?

Comment: Take just one cos to start with, and assume you know it holds for all factors except for the last one.

Comment: @mathreadler well it gives cos(x).Un=1/2.sin(2x)^2.sin(2^2 x)....sin(2^n.x)

Comment: @mathreadler can u tell me please where i made the mistake ?

Comment: I'm happy to see Michael could write it down. What he wrote is basically what I meant.

Answer (score 16):

Easy to see that $|U_1(x)|\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and $|U_2(x)|\leq\frac{3}{4}$ for every $x$.

Assume that $|U_k(x)|\leq\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^k$ for every real $x$ and every $k\leq n$, for some $n\ge2$.

- If $|\sin{x}|\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$, then $$|U_{n+1}(x)|=|\sin x|\cdot|U_n(2x)|\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^n=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$
- If $|\sin{x}|\geq\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$, then $|\cos{x}|\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $|\sin{x}\sin2x|=|2(1-\cos^2x)\cos{x}|\leq\frac{3}{4}$.
  Thus, $$|U_{n+1}(x)|=|\sin{x}\sin2x|\cdot|U_{n-1}(4x)|\leq\frac{3}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{n-1}=\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{n+1}$$

By induction on $n\ge1$, we are done.

Comment: Nice split into cases.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

Let us assume it holds for $n=k$, that is: $|U_k| \leq \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^k$

Now what we want to show for the product for $n=k+1$ reduces to $\leq \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{k-1} \sin(2^{k}x)\sin(2^{k+1}x)$, right? If we multiply it with $\cos(2^{k}x)$, what happens?

Comment: (√3/2)^k-1 . 1/2 . sin(2^k+1 . x )^2

Comment: Yes, and how is that bounded?

Comment: honnestly i don't know what to do next

Comment: i've got no idea can u help please