# About an integral inequality

Tags: integration, inequality

Let $ u$ be a nonnegative continous function defined in $[x_0, x_0+a ] $, and $\alpha \in(0,1)$.

Prove that if $$u(x) \le \int\limits_{x_0}^x \! Cu^\alpha(t) dt$$
with $C\ge 0$ then
$$u(x) \le (C(1-\alpha)(x-x_0))^{1/(1-\alpha)} .$$

Comment: I made an edit, is that what you mean?

Comment: yes it is exactly this. How to use Cauchy-Schwarz to this?

Comment: @Martin R Here is not your post and I don't understand you.

Comment: @Martin R See here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2043127/prove-that-vert-sinx-sin2x-sin22x-cdots-sin2nx-vert-left-frac-s DiD edited my post. My solution was written better. Why Did did do it? I think it's much worse than to add limits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $x_0 = 0$. We can also 
assume that $u$ is not identically zero and
$$
    x_1 = \inf \{ x \in [0, a] \mid u(x) > 0 \}  = 0
$$
Otherwise do the following estimate on the interval $[x_1, a]$, this
will only strengthen the inequality.

Define $v(x)$ for
 $0 \le x \le a$ as
$$
   v(x) = \left( \int_0^x u^\alpha(t) \, dt \right)^{1-\alpha} 
$$ 
Then $v(0) = 0$. $v$ is positive and differentiable on the interval $(0, a)$, with
$$
 v'(x) = (1-\alpha) \left( \int_0^x u^\alpha(t) \, dt \right)^{-\alpha}
  u^\alpha(x) \\
 \le (1-\alpha) \left( \int_0^x u^\alpha(t) \, dt \right)^{-\alpha}
  C^\alpha \left( \int_0^x u^\alpha(t) \, dt \right)^{\alpha}
 = (1-\alpha) C
$$
It follows that for $x \ge 0$
$$
 v(x) \le (1-\alpha) C x
$$
and therefore
$$
 u(x) \le C \int_0^x u^\alpha(t) \, dt
 = C v(x)^{1/(1-\alpha)} \le (C(1-\alpha)(x-x_0))^{1/(1-\alpha)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{WRONG ANSWER}$ (I cannot assert the first inequality in terms of derivatives)

Derive the expression with respect to $x$ applying Leibniz's rule resulting 
$$u'(x)\leq Cu^{\alpha}(x)$$

This is an easy diff. equation
$$\frac{u'(x)}{u^{\alpha}(x)}\leq C$$

Integrating in the interval yields to the desired expression.

Comment: But the function is not assumed to be differentiable, merely continuous.

Comment: completely true @Dominik

Comment: Remember that requires es that $f(x)−f(y) \rightarrow 0$ as x−y→0

Differentiability requires that $f(x)−f(y) \rightarrow 0$ as $x−y \rightarrow 0$ **and** $f(x)−f(y) \rightarrow 0$ at least as fast as $x−y \rightarrow 0$ with the ratio still having a limit.

Comment: How do you obtain the first inequality? $f \le g$ does not imply $f' \le g'$ in general. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I did not think about it... It is completely wrong.
Thank you @MartinR for telling me!

Comment: @HBR: If the solution is wrong then you might want to delete the answer.