# Gronwall-type inequality with square-root

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

So i came across the following inequality:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u^2\mathrm{d}x\right)\leq K\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u^2\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}, \,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{in} [0,T).$$

and i'm trying to bound the integral. Is there any variation of Gronwall's inequality that works for that case, i.e., can I somehow conclude that
$$ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u^2\mathrm{d}x\right) \leq C\exp\left(\int_0^t K\,\mathrm{d}s\right)? $$

Obs: in this case, $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^n),$ so there are no problems with the integral itself.

Comment: I don't know if that helps anything, but defining $y(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}u^2(t)dx,$ this implies

$$y(t)\leq y(0)+K\int_0^t y(s)^{1/2} \mathrm{d}s$$

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050893/42969.