# Show that $u(x) \leq [c(1-\alpha)|x-x_0|]^{(1-\alpha)^{-1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u(x)$ be a non-negative continuous function on the interval $I := \{x:|x-x_0|\leq a\}; a > 0,$ and $c > 0$ be a given constant, and $u(x)\leq |\int_{x_0}^{x} cu^{\alpha}(t) dt|, 0< \alpha < 1$. Show that $u(x) \leq [c(1-\alpha)|x-x_0|]^{(1-\alpha)^{-1}}$

Attempt: I'm trying to argue for $x \geq x_0$ and $x\leq x_0$ separately. For $x\geq x_0$, define $h(x):=\int_{x_0}^{x} cu^{\alpha}(t) dt$. Clearly $h(x_0)=0$ and $h$ is differentiable. Now differentiating w.r.t  $x$ we get $h'(x)=cu^{\alpha}(x)\leq ch^{\alpha}(x)$. Now here we get a differential inequality $h'(x)\leq ch^{\alpha}(x)$. If I solve this by separation of variable then I get the required inequality but the problem is I don't think I can solve like this as I get $\frac{h(t)}{h^{\alpha}(t)} \leq c$ the denominator is $0$ when $x=x_0$ and $h$ might be unbounded.
I'm stuck here please help me out.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050893/42969

Comment: Thanks. Help me close the question